# Update HTML table automatically from MySQL table in real time

Tags: html, mysql

From the title of the question, I'm trying to update a HTML table from a MySQL table in real time. The webpage is meant to never close or refreshed using the refresh button.

I understand that Ajax can help me with that but I searched all over the net and can't find a proper example that makes use of it with a table.

I'm creating a type of digital menu that allows customers in a restaurant to order food online and allows the manager to see what the customer has ordered.

I want to do this in real time so that a manager of a restaurant can keep track of what food has been served to the table.

I'm currently using a tick box that determines if the food has been served. The problem is that the tick box will untick itself every time the page refreshes in order to receive any new data, if any(I'm using a meta tag that refreshes itself every 5 seconds).

Below is my code for displaying the HTML table from collected data from a database in MySQL.

```html
<html>

<head>
      <title>See and delete data in MySQL Database</title>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
   </head>
 <body>
 <form method = "post" action = "delete_data.php">
    <input name = "remove" type = "submit" id = "remove" class="remove" name="remove" value = "Clear table">
  </form>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT number_d, food_d, quantity_d, table_d FROM food_to_serve";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
     <th>Number</th>
     <th>Food</th>
  <th>Quantity</th>
  <th>Table</th>
  </tr>";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
 {
    echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['number_d'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['food_d'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['quantity_d'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['table_d']. "</td>";
 echo "<td> <form action=\"\" method=\"get\">
   <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"food_status\" value=\"food_stat\">Reached table<br>
   </form> </td>";
 echo "</tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

echo "</table>";

$conn->close();
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: One of the solution to your problem is JavaScript `localStoage`. I am not sure how you can implement it within the php code but I can tell you how to make it work -> Inside your `if ($result->num_rows > 0)` you could create a browser localStorage and store the value say "true", next time the page reloads before connection check whether that localStorage value is "true" check the unticked box. - basically **make use of the feature that JavaScript `localStorage` does not clear its value on page refresh**

Comment: You have to set the checkboxes `checked` property from the code and preserve it when it is changed.